# Update binded child wpf when parent change wpf

Tags: wpf, events, data-binding

Im using several controls in my main window.
one grid at top that has a list of licenses and i want to display the information of the license each time i change the selection of the grid

MainWindow:

```
<dx:DXWindow
x:Class="LicenceManagerWPF.Forms.frmCustomerLicense"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2016"  
xmlns:ctr="clr-namespace:LicenceManagerWPF.Controls"
Title="CustomerLicence" Height="800" Width="1000" 
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="DXWindow_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="200" Height="200*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="25" Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel  x:Name="Stack_Top" Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="0" >
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btnRefresh" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}" ToolTip="Refresh Licenses" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Refresh_32x32.png}" Content="Resfresh" />
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btndNew" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}"  ToolTip="New License" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=New_32x32.png}" Content="New Customer"  />
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btnDelete" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}"  ToolTip="Delete Licence" Content="Delete" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=Cancel_32x32.png}"/>
        <dx:SimpleButton x:Name="btnEdit" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BtnSmall}" ToolTip="Edit Customer" Glyph="{dx:DXImage Image=EditContact_32x32.png}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Customer: " FontSize="20" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customer.Name}" Margin="5" FontSize="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ctr:Licences x:Name="grdLicenses" Grid.Row="1">
    </ctr:Licences>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <ctr:LicenseDetail x:Name="ct_LicenseDetail" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ctr:LicenceLog x:Name="ct_LicenseLog" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The grid is ctr_Licenses and the other control is LicenseDetail which should show the information of the license selected, this is the licenseDetail control:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" 
         xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 
         xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" x:Class="LicenceManagerWPF.Controls.LicenseDetail"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="600" x:Name="ctrl_LicenseDetail"           >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SmallMargin" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TabMargin" TargetType="FrameworkElement" >
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SmalllMarginTextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SmallMargin}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">            
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SmallMarginDropDown" BasedOn="{StaticResource SmallMargin }" TargetType="dx:DropDownButton" >            
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SmallMarginText" BasedOn="{StaticResource SmallMargin}" TargetType="TextBox">            
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ckkStyle" TargetType="dxe:CheckEdit" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabMargin}">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    </Style>               
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="License Detail" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="Serial Number:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmalllMarginTextBlock}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedLicense.SerialNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  x:Name="txtSerialNum" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmalllMarginTextBlock}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Product:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmalllMarginTextBlock}" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <dx:DropDownButton x:Name="dropDownButton" Width="180"  Content="Product" Style="{StaticResource SmallMarginDropDown}">                      
        </dx:DropDownButton>
        <TextBlock Text="Status:" Style="{StaticResource SmalllMarginTextBlock}" />
         <TextBlock Text="" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource SmalllMarginTextBlock}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Description:" Style="{StaticResource SmalllMarginTextBlock}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBox Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource SmallMargin}" Width="350" />
    <dx:DXTabControl Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="tabAttributes" Header="License Attributes" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Activation Mode:" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}" />
                <dx:DropDownButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}" ButtonKind="Repeat" />
                <TextBlock Text="Grace Period:" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <dxe:SpinEdit Width="80" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}" MinValue="0" MaxValue="100" IsReadOnly="True" Value="10" Mask="n0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Days" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}"  />
                </StackPanel>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Grid.Row="2" Content="Expiration Date" IsChecked="False" />
                <dxe:DateNavigator Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="185" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Max Computers:" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource TabMargin}"/>
                <dxe:SpinEdit Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" Margin="2.5,2.5,2.5,1" MinValue="0" MaxValue="100" IsReadOnly="True" Value="10" Mask="n0"/>
            </Grid>
        </dx:DXTabItem>
        <dx:DXTabItem Header="Product Features" x:Name="tabProductFeatures" Visibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="Standard" Name="chkStandard" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}" />
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="Admin Mode" Name="chkAdminMode" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}" />
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="Batch Mode" Name="chkBatchMode" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}" />
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="Custom Data Series" Name="chkCustomDataSeries" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}" />
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="Local DataBase" Name="LocalDataBase" IsReadOnly="True" IsChecked="True" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}"/>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="Cloud Data Base" Name="CloudDataBase" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>               
        </dx:DXTabItem>
        <dx:DXTabItem Name="tabComputers" Header="Computers">
            <dxg:GridControl Name="grdComputers">                    
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </dx:DXTabItem>
        <dx:DXTabItem Name="tabMain_Schedule" Header="Maint. Schedule">
            <dxg:GridControl>                    
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </dx:DXTabItem>
        <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="tabFeaturePB" Header="Product Features">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="pb" Name="chkpb" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}" />
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="pb2" Name="chkpb2" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource ckkStyle}" />                    
            </StackPanel>
        </dx:DXTabItem>

    </dx:DXTabControl>        
</Grid>
```

The DataContext class of the mainwindows is this

```
public class CustomerLicenses
{
    private Customer _Customer;
    private LicenseList _Licenses;
    private License _SelectedLicense;
    //private Guid _SelectedSerial;
    //public delegate void SelectLicenseEventArg(String SerialNum);
    //public event SelectLicenseEventArg SelectLicense; 


    public CustomerLicenses(Customer Customer)
    {
        _Customer = Customer;
    }

    public CustomerLicenses(Customer customer, LicenseList licenses)
    {
        _Customer = customer;
        _Licenses = licenses;
    }

    public CustomerLicenses()
    {
        _Customer = new Customer();
        _Licenses = new LicenseList();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return _Customer; }
        set
        {
            if (_Customer != value)
            {
                this._Customer = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Customer");
            }
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public LicenseList Licenses
    {
        get { return _Licenses;}
        set
        {
            if (_Licenses != value)
            {
                this._Licenses = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Licenses");
            }
        }
    }


    private DataTable GetLicensesTable()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn []{
            new DataColumn("SerialNumber",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Product",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Status",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("ActivationMode",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("MaxComputers", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("NumActive",typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Description",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("License",typeof(object))
        });
        _Licenses.ForEach((x) => {
            var rw = dt.NewRow();
            rw["SerialNumber"] = x.SerialNumber;
            rw["Product"] = x.Product.Name;
            rw["Status"] = x.Status;
            rw["ActivationMode"] = Enum.GetName(typeof(ActivationModeEnum), x.ActivationMode);   //x.ActivationMode;
            rw["MaxComputers"] = x.MaxComputers;
            rw["NumActive"] = Activated(x.Product.ProductId);
            rw["Description"] = x.Description;
            rw["License"] = x;
            dt.Rows.Add(rw);
        });
        return dt;
    }        

    public DataTable LicensesTable{
        get { return GetLicensesTable(); }
   }

    [DataMember]
    public License SelectedLicense {
        get { return _SelectedLicense;}
        set {
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedLicense");
            _SelectedLicense = value;
        }
    }    
public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

    }
}
```

In this part im populating the textblock with the serial, and is ok it shows when i start the app `cause takes the first license but if i select another license the text does not change.

```
 TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedLicense.SerialNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  x:Name="txtSerialNum" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SmalllMarginTextBlock}"
```

This is how i assaing the value when the grid chanege selection

```
  private void GridRowSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var Record = (DataRowView)grdLicenses.grdLicences.SelectedItem;
            var SelectedLicense = (License)Record["License"];
            _CustomerLicense.SelectedLicense = SelectedLicense;                

            //Customer_Detail.DataContext = SelectedCustomer;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

How can i update the child when the item is selected in the grid.

Regards

Comment: The fastest way would be to remove if frome setter of customer property if (_Customer != value)
            {
                this._Customer = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Customer");
            }.      And then, on rowSelected just 'CustomerLicense.Customer = CUstomerLicensce.Customer'

Comment: 2nd fast way would be to implement private void Notify, in which you would write something like;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Customer");
             and just call this method on gridRow selected.  The last way would be to implement some truly observable collection, there are some answers on Stack how to do this.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sTrenat, as you said i checked the class and i was wrong implementing the propertyfotify

i changed to this

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomerLicenses: System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```